# Chat client without select?

Tags: python

I am currently making a chat server and clientusing python, I have come across an issue with select as it doesn not work on Windows but does on Linux, I wish to know if it is possible to run the server on my Linux machine and rceate a client that will work on windows that would still be able to communicate with it as most of theople that I wish to talk to using this use windows.

Comment: Have a look at either IOCP or threading/processes on windows

Comment: Thank you, i was thinking threading would work but wasn't entirely sure if was advised, at least with this i feel much more reassured about using it:)

Comment: Note that select *does* work on Windows... only on sockets. Which should be fine for your chat application. It wouldn't be if you were interested in files/pipes etc.

Comment: @Bakuriu in a basic chat program where only text will be exchanged would that require pipes?

Answer (score 0):

check out how its done using tornado [chat example](https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio/tree/master/examples/chatroom), clients are browsers.